# Disable globally "Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)" with Multisite

Tags: plugins, thumbnails, wp-config

I would like to disable the "Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)" function for all blogs in my WordPress Multisite setup.

This function is available in Dashboard, Settings/Media.

The best solution would be PHP code in wp-config.php or simple plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable cropping, insert this below code in `disable-automatic-image-crop.php` file in your mu-plugins folder:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Disable Automatic Image Crop
Author: Wordpress Community
Description: https://gist.github.com/czenzel/0f5888cbbfa4a857e56361dd3bc19b39
*/
add_action( 'init', 'czc_disable_extra_image_sizes' );
add_filter( 'image_resize_dimensions', 'czc_disable_crop', 10, 6 );
function czc_disable_crop( $enable, $orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h, $crop )
{
    // Instantly disable this filter after the first run
    // remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    // return image_resize_dimensions( $orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h, false );
    return false;
}
function czc_disable_extra_image_sizes() {
    foreach ( get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $size ) {
        remove_image_size( $size );
    }
}
?>
```

It's completely disabled automatic image cropping for all sizes.